# How to fix 'RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, math

After doing *for loop* in my code, there is an error in one line:

`RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars`

and in another line two errors:

`RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars`

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arcsin`

I found it might be problem with float values, but im not sure about it and im typing it here for looking yours help. :)

Here is the code:

```py
T_max = 0.5 * v_PM(Me) * RTOD 
DT = (90 - T_max) - np.fix(90 - T_max) 
n = int(T_max * 2)

P = np.zeros((n+1))    
T = np.zeros((n+1))
M = np.zeros((n+1))
RR = np.zeros((n+1))
LR = np.zeros((n+1))
SL = np.zeros((n+1))

for m in range(n+1):
    T[m] = (DT + m) * DTOR
    func = lambda x: T[m] - v_PM(x) 
    M[m] = brentq(func, 1, Me+1) 
    M[0] = 0
    P[m] = TR * np.tan(T[m]) #X-AXIS POINTS
    P[0] = 0
    RR[m] = -TR / P[m]
    RR[0] = 0
    LR[m] = (np.tan(T[m] + np.arcsin(1 / M[m]))) 
    LR[0] = 0
    SL[m] = -RR[m] 
    SL[0] = 0
```

I defined earlier (before loop) `v_PM` and it's equal

`v_PM = lambda x : (A * np.arctan(np.sqrt(B * (x ** 2 - 1))) - np.arctan(np.sqrt(x ** 2 - 1)))`

As i mentioned, error 
`RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars`
refer to `RR[m] = -TR / P[m]`

and two errors 
`RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars` 
and

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arcsin`  refers to:

`LR[m] = (np.tan(T[m] + np.arcsin(1 / M[m])))`

I put there also `P[0] = 0` and `M[0] = 0` etc. because i want to have first element as 0.

I dont know if i can forget about this error and move on with my code or if it is some serious problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: At first you should find out which line causes the warning. This is usually shown in the Traceback.

Comment: Try something like `if abs(P[m]) <1E-6: print(m, P[m]`. Just before the division to find out what values are causing the problem. You can do something similar for T[m] and M[m]. Knowing these values may help you understand what's happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are not actual errors, but warnings. 
They are there because you are trying to divide something by zero.

Namely, you are setting `M[0] = 0` and then dividing by `M[0]` (at first iteration, where `m = 0`) and same for `P[0]`.

The question is, what do you want the first values to be?

Maybe a solution would be initialize the zero values as you wish (before the loop) and start the loop with `m=1` (so using `for m in range(1,n+1):`). Is that what you needed?

However, the warning may still be there if at different iterations `P[m]` or `M[m]` will be zero.

```
T_max = 0.5 * v_PM(Me) * RTOD 
DT = (90 - T_max) - np.fix(90 - T_max) 
n = int(T_max * 2)

P = np.zeros((n+1))    
T = np.zeros((n+1))
M = np.zeros((n+1))
RR = np.zeros((n+1))
LR = np.zeros((n+1))
SL = np.zeros((n+1))

# initialize your values
M[0] = 0 # actually not needed
P[0] = 0 # actually not needed
RR[0] = 0 # actually not needed
LR[0] = 0 # actually not needed
SL[0] = 0 # actually not needed
T[m] = (DT) * DTOR

for m in range(1,n+1):
    T[m] = (DT + m) * DTOR
    #Mach from T[i] using T[i] = v_PM (FALSE POSITION)
    func = lambda x: T[m] - v_PM(x) 
    M[m] = brentq(func, 1, Me+1) 
    P[m] = TR * np.tan(T[m]) #X-AXIS POINTS

    #RR SLOPES
    RR[m] = -TR / P[m]

    #LR slopes
    LR[m] = (np.tan(T[m] + np.arcsin(1 / M[m]))) 
    SL[m] = -RR[m]
```

Answer (score 4):

Those warning messages can be ignored using:

`np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')`

Another idea, is to add or substract a very small number from the denominator depending on use case:

Eg. `np.log(y / (1 - y))`, for `y = 1.0` it will raise a zero division error.
To avoid it, one common approach is to subtract a small value such as `1e-15` from y:

`y -= 1e15`